# How to navigate from detail Page to Master Detail Page?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

The button from detail page cannot go to a master detail page. It keeps displaying error "break exception". Maybe I am not implementing this right. Please help :(

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us what you're doing.  A vague description of the problem is not really helpful - show us the relevant portion of your code.

Comment: @Jason .. I can't navigate to a MasterDetail page via a button.
    private async void SignIn_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync( new NavigationPage( new template.MasterDetailPage()));

        }

Comment: MasterDetail needs to be the root, it can't exist inside of a NavigationPage

Comment: so I cant do LoginPage -> MainPage(masterdetail) ?

Comment: you can swap out the existing root page with a new MasterDetail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master detail page does not work like that. You do not navigate from master to detail and back. Master is always available but on Phone it slides out like a drawer and on tablet it is present along with the detail page if not intentionally hidden.

```cs
public class App : Application
{
    MasterDetailPage masterdetail;
    Page detailpage;
    Page masterpage;

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        masterdetail= new MasterDetailPage();
        detailpage = new MyDetailPage();
        masterpage = new Page();
        masterdetail.Master = masterpage;
        masterdetail.Detail = detailpage;
        MainPage = masterdetail;        
    }

}
```

**On Phone**

With the above example you would see the detailpage only unless you slide out left to right or change the masterdetail.IsPresented to true in code.

**On Tablet**

If masterdetail.IsPresent is true the masterpage would show to the left and the detail to the right without any other code modifying this.

**IsPresented**

What you may be looking for is accessing the IsPresented field from a button click.

```cs
public partial class MyDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    Button abutton;    

    MyDetailPage()
    {
        abutton = new Button();
        abutton.click += (o,s) => {App.masterdetail.IsPresented == true ? false : true}
    }
}
```

**General Usage**

The general intention of this layout design being that that master page leads to sub navigation detail pages in something like a Contacts List -> Specific Contact Details type relationship.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/

**Navigation To MasterDetail From Other Page**

```cs
button.click += (o,s) => 
{
    var detailpage = new Page();
    var masterpage = new Page();
    var masterdetailpage = new MasterDetailPage();
    masterdetailpage.Master = masterpage;
    masterdetailpage.Detail = detailpage;
    App.Current.MainPage = masterdetailpage;
}
```

**Doing the Same Thing From Xaml with Commands**

The below example creates a command in the page's.cs code and binds it to to a button on the xaml for the page.

```cs
public partial class CurrentPage : ContentPage
{
    private ICommand goToMasterDetailCommand;
    public ICommand goToMasterDetail
    {
        return goToMasterDetailCommand ?? (goToMasterDetailCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteGoToMasterDetail()));
    }

    private async Task ExecuteGoToMasterDetail()
    {
        var detailpage = new Page();
        var masterpage = new Page();
        var masterdetailpage = new MasterDetailPage();
        masterdetailpage.Master = masterpage;
        masterdetailpage.Detail = detailpage;
        App.Current.MainPage = masterdetailpage;
    }
}
```

```xml
<Button
x:Name="GoToButton"
Text="Go To Master Detail"
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
Command="{Binding goToMasterDetail}"
IsVisible="true">
```

Comment: I am aiming to Launch the MasterDetailPage via a Button. Basically what I am doing here is if the user click the button. it will navigate to the masterdetail page

Comment: Updated answer with example of jumping to a master detail page from outside of page

Comment: Can I use that in with XAML?

Comment: You're killing me smalls.. adding an example of commanding one moment

Answer (score 0):

Please try 
    `Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterDetailsPage();`
Upon button click